# Websocket without edit server

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

I have a website with a radiostatus, but right now that radio status uses AJAX to keep it up-to-date. I've heared about websocket. It should be better to send te radiostatus to all users with websocked, instead of with AJAX that gets everything out of a SQL database. But the point is that we only have a FTP, so we are not owner of the server. i can't find any websocket that don't have a code that need's to be executed on the server. And we can't execute because it's not our server. Does anyone has a solution.

i hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you need to have a service running on the server to coordinate the WebSocket connections and communications.

An alternative you might be interested in is [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/) which provides that server side processing and communication to all connected clients.